# Is there any function in python similar to fzero in matlab?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to solve the following equation in python.

[image: equation]

It can be implemented in Matlab by fzero function as follows:

```
    K=5;
    H=6;
    u=100;
    fun=@(x) -(K*(-H+log(1+H/x)*(x+H)))/(log(2)*x^2*(log2((x+H)/x))^2*(x+H))+u;
    xx=fzero(fun,[1e-3,1])
```

However, I can't find a suitable function in python. `scipy.optimize.fsolve` needs the initial value. Moreover, it is always with unexplained errors. Could you please tell me how to implement it in python?

The python code is as follows:

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
K=5
H=6
u=100
def func(x,K,H,u):
    return (-(K*(-H+math.log(1+H/x)*(x+H)))/(math.log(2)*(x**2)*(math.log((x+H)/x,2))**2*(x+H))+u)
print(fsolve(func,0.5,args=(K,H,u)))
```

The error is as follows:
return (-(K*(-H+math.log(1+H/x)*(x+H)))/(math.log(2)*(x**2)*(math.log((x+H)/x,2))**2*(x+H))+u) ValueError: math domain error

Comment: "unexplained errors"?  We like to explain errors - **provided** you give us enough information.

Comment: The error is as follows: return (-(K*(-H+math.log(1+H/x)*(x+H)))/(math.log(2)*(x**2)*(math.log((x+H)/x,2))**2*(x+H))+u)

ValueError: math domain error

Comment: Sounds like a `math.log` is getting a negative argument.

Comment: So you can debug it your self by divide and conquer: break the complicated statement down into smaller elements and find out which term is giving the error.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. The input of math.log() is positive. I tried to change the smaller elements that I can change, but the error still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is linked to the initial guess of your root and how it affects the stability of the implementation of the algortihm. For example, if you swap 0.5 by 1e-3, fsolve converges. I propose below an alternative script which makes use of a bracket algorithm and which converges without problems, provided that the root lies within the bracket and that the images of each end of the bracket are of opposite sign. If any of the latter conditions are not enforced, then the algorithm will let you know about it.

```
from numpy import log, log2
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar


def func(x, K, H, u):
    return (u - K * (log(1 + H / x) * (x + H) - H)
            / log(2) / x ** 2 / log2((x + H) / x) ** 2 / (x + H))


sol = root_scalar(func, args=(5, 6, 100), method='toms748', bracket=[1e-3, 1])
print(sol.root, func(sol.root, 5, 6, 100))
# 0.0784837307625566 4.263256414560601e-14
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help, which solves my urgent need.